# What happens to PHP file lock if the script times out or is terminated while the lock was on?

Tags: php, locking, flock

My question is best illustrated with this PHP code sample:

```
$file = fopen($filePath, "wb");
if($file !== false)
{
    //Obtain exclusive lock
    if(flock($file, LOCK_EX))
    {
        //Script times out or is terminated here
        //say, due to it using too much RAM, etc.
        //...

        //Release exclusive lock
        flock($file, LOCK_UN);
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

What would happen to the lock?

Comment: It's released; though I don't remember the specifics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just made a couple of tests on the following shared server:

```
PHP Version 5.4.34
Linux 3.12.35.1418868052 #1 SMP x86_64
```

And my conclusion is that file locks *are released* automatically once the script finishes running, even in case of a fatal error, a timeout or out-of-memory fault that terminates the script, or if I comment out `flock($file, LOCK_UN);` function.

Answer (score -1):

I actually think it is not released automatically. To make sure your script won't keep the file in a locked state, you will need to register a shutdown callback and unlock all the locked files there.

```
register_shutdown_function('unlock_files');
```

where clean_state is a function that goes through all your locked files (so you need to keep track of them) and unlock them.

The shutdown function is called when a fatal error, a timeout or an out of memory error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the info about `register_shutdown_function` function. But your original assumption is not correct. The links are released as I posted in my own answer.

Comment: What is this comment based on?  "I think" is probably not a good basis for overengineering a solution...  [citation needed], I think!